# Loading ImageMagick from Apache (XAMPP)

Tags: apache, imagemagick, xampp

I wrote an image manipulating program with PHP/imagick. The server is installed under XAMPP, which resides in a flash drive.

Now everything works fine except that ImageMagick needs to be installed on every machine I use.

To solve the problem and make it easier, I copied the ImageMagick folder to the flash drive, removed ImageMagick from Windows Environment Variables, and modified Apache config (tried both httpd.conf and extra/httpd-xampp.conf).

**httpd.conf**

```
SetEnv MAGICK_HOME "/xmapp/ImageMagick"
```

**extra/httpd-xampp.conf**

```
<IfModule env_module>    <----- enabled
SetEnv MIBDIRs "xampp/php/extras/mibs"
SetEnv MAGICK_HOME "/xampp/ImageMagick"    <-----
SetEnv MySQL_HOME "/xmapp/mysql/bin"
```

However, when I started Apache, I got a error message saying "Cannot find CORE_RL_wand_.dll". I'm pretty sure the path is correct and no files are missing. It seems that Apache just can't load ImageMagick.

Here are the versions I'm using:

- XAMPP 1.8.2 (Apache 2.4.4 / PHP 5.4.19)
- ImageMagick-6.8.7-1-Q16-x86-dll
- php_imagick_ts.dll for PHP 5.4 (from [Mikko](http://valokuva.org/new-builds-for-php-5-4-and-php-5-3/))

Does anyone have any experience with portable ImageMagick/XAMPP?

Is this the correct way to load ImageMagick from Apache?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add to the system path the `Imagick`'s path. Maybe you also have to add as environment variable the `MAGICK_HOME`. That solved my problem.